# Error on Publish Quality Gate Result in Azure DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: sonarqube, devops, pipeline, release

In my particular case I have to run the sonar analysis in the release, I can’t do it in the pipeline because it depends on the environment.
I have been using sonar in azure devops for several years but always running sonar from the pipeline
In this very special case I have to run the sonar in the release and this is where the error occurs.

Error in: Publish Quality Gate Result:
##[error]The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EPHy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAvNv.png)

Run Code Analysis: no Warning and no error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdqBm.png)

if i run it manually on my pc it works fine:

sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=SQLAA" -D"sonar.sources=Develop" -D"sonar.host.url=https://sssss.ssss.uuuu" -D"sonar.login=nnnnnnnnnnnn" -D"sonar.sql.dialect=tsql" -D"sonar.language=sql" -D"sonar.exclusions=DefinitionName/**" -D"sonar.scm.disabled=true" -D"sonar.verbose=true"

[I use standalone scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iENth.png)

[is a simple release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXIHY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4uAL.png)
It was tried as seen in the images, but it gives an error